# Is it possible to turn off 2nd level caching for UserType?

Tags: hibernate, caching, localization, internationalization, usertype

I struggle with the i18n setup in my Spring/Hibernate application. I have now tried to follow this recipe: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1377072/Internationalized-Data-in-Hibernate

And it works as long as I don't use the second level cache. When I do use it the first value is cached and return even if I later change the language. (Through the disassemble and assemble methods). I really hope someone can help me with this one, cause I need to cache the CarType entity, just not the userType-part. (The I18nLocaleHolder operates on an in-memory map)

Thank you!

Here is part of the entity class:

```
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
   @Immutable
   @Table(name = "CAR_TYPE")
   public class CarType implements Serializable {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      @Type(type = "LocalizedLabelUserType")
      private String description;

        ...
```

And here is the userType:
    public class LocalizedLabelUserType implements UserType {

```
   @Override
   public int[] sqlTypes() {
      return new int[] { Types.INTEGER };
   }

   @Override
   public Class<String> returnedClass() {
      return String.class;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
      return x == y;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
      return x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode();
   }

   @Override
   public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException,
         SQLException {
      Long labelId = (Long) LongType.INSTANCE.nullSafeGet(rs, names, session, owner);
      return I18nLocaleHolder.getDescription(labelId, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage());
   }

   @Override
   public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException,
         SQLException {
      Long code = I18nLocaleHolder.getCode((String) value, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage());
      LongType.INSTANCE.nullSafeSet(st, code, index, session);
   }

   @Override
   public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isMutable() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
      return (Serializable) value;
   }

   @Override
   public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return cached;
   }

   @Override
   public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
      return original;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@Immutable` would need to be removed, otherwise Hibernate will not detect the changed description to class `CarType`.

Then changing the caching of `CarType` from `READ_ONLY` to `READ_WRITE` would still allow the entity to be cached, but when the entity get's updated on the database, the cache will reflect the new value of `description`:

```
@Table(name = "CAR_TYPE")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
 public class CarType implements Serializable {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering me. I have tried your solution, but unfortunately it did not work. However I managed to get it working, but the solution is a bit hacky, so I will no post it as an answer. To sum it up I return the description from nullSafeGet, and in disassemble I get and return the code. Then all the following calls to assemble will include the code and I can get the correct text from the language cache. In addition I had to modify the Query annotation where I used the Cachable annotation. (Needed to input language, so this was definitely hacky)